# Need help creating a csv output file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

Need help in creating a csv output file using pandas. I am only getting one line of data in my csv output file and there should be five. I have tried adding print statements in various places to check if my input csv file is iterating and it is. Not sure why its not storing all five results in the sentiment.csv file. There are 5 urls in the urls2.csv file so one would expect 5 results in the sentiment.csv but I am only getting one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import spacy
from spacytextblob.spacytextblob import SpacyTextBlob
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
nlp.add_pipe('spacytextblob')
df = pd.read_csv("urls2.csv")
urls = df["Address"].tolist()

url_sent_score = []
url_sent_label = []
total_pos = []
total_neg = []
for count, x in enumerate(urls):
  url = x
  headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'}
  res = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
  html_page = res.text

  soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
  for script in soup(["script", "style","meta","label","header","footer"]):
    script.decompose()
    page_text = (soup.get_text()).lower()
    page_text = page_text.strip().replace("  ","")
    page_text = "".join([s for s in page_text.splitlines(True) if s.strip("\r\n")])
    doc = nlp(page_text)

  sentiment = doc._.blob.polarity
  sentiment = round(sentiment,2)

  if sentiment > 0:
    sent_label = "Positive"
  else:
    sent_label = "Negative"

url_sent_label.append(sent_label)
url_sent_score.append(sentiment)
positive_words = []
negative_words = []

for x in doc._.blob.sentiment_assessments.assessments:
  if x[1] > 0:
    positive_words.append(x[0][0])
  elif x[1] < 0:
    negative_words.append(x[0][0])
  else:
    pass

total_pos.append(', '.join(set(positive_words)))
total_neg.append(', '.join(set(negative_words)))

data = {
      'Sentiment Score':url_sent_score,
      'Sentiment Label':url_sent_label,
      'Positive Words':total_pos,
      'Negative Words':total_neg}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("sentiment.csv")
df.to_json("sentiment.json",orient="split")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, make sure that your code is indented correctly and include the current output file.

Comment: Why do you have escape characters all over the place? `\[\]` isn't valid syntax

Comment: Your `csv` will only be as good as source dataframe.  Print that (it shouldn't be too large if you only expect 5 lines).

Comment: I tried printing the source dataframe and I still only get one record.

Comment: The escape characters were added by the stackoverflow textbox.

Comment: Hey! Welcome to SO. The code is a little bit distorted, so it may be not entirely clear what the issue is. In addition, it would be very helpful to know what versions of `pandas` and Python you are using?

Comment: Also, why do you expect five rows in your output? The malformed code makes it hard to understand. Maybe you just need to transpose your frame in the end?

Comment: If the frame only has one record, then the csv will only have one line.  If that's not what you want, you need to correct the code that creates the frame.  This is a dateframe issue, not a csv one!

Answer (score 0):

The function `.to_csv` writes a file with a default field delimiter is comma (,), see this documentation (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). You should change the field delimiter of your file to a line, like this:

```
df.to_csv("sentiment.csv",sep="\n")
```

where `"\n"` writes each row of the dataframe in a new line.

Comment: Sorry, still only getting one record. Using the sep="\n" I still get only a single record but with each column on a separate line.

Comment: Here is my urls2.csv file if someone wants to try it on their system.
Address
https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2174894/?ref_=tt_urv
https://www.imdb.com/review/rw8563215/?ref_=tt_urv
https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2174283/?ref_=tt_urv
https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2214814/?ref_=tt_urv
https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2291287/?ref_=tt_urv

Comment: I also tried with df.to_json and I only get a single record.

Comment: What exactly did you get as the output of one line?

Comment: Sentiment Score Sentiment Label Positive Words  Negative Words
0       0.2     Positive        first, interesting, far, strong, clear, more, general, amusing, enjoyable, true, really, best, charismatic, special, liked, competent, exactly, absolutely, spiri>

Comment: Code is fixed now. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Can you also edit the indentation?